# Want to display simple product's attribute on product detail Page

Tags: magento2

Can anyone help me to display simple products custom attribute value on grouped.phtml page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in

> app\design\frontend\Company\theme\Magento_GroupedProduct\templates\product\view\type\grouped.phtml

```
<?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <?php 
         $attribute = $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('price'); 
         $attr_value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_item);
         ?>
```

Product price : `<?php echo $attr_value; ?>`

Please let me know if its work for you.

Comment: It doesn't work for associated product custom attributes, it works only for the system ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$code = "your_product_attribute_code";
$label = $_product->getAttributeText($code);
$value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Answer (score 0):

@TBI Infotech can you try to see if your code works on a custom attribute? Price is a system attribute. It is not working for any custom attributes I created by myself. Seems to be a common issue for Magento 2, asked by a few people during the past several months.